# How to install Rust toolset on RHEL in EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rust, rhel

I tried installing Rust Toolset to get Cargo:

```
yum install rust-toolset-7
No package rust-toolset-7 available.
```

I also tried:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms
Error: 'rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.
```

Comment: Official sources recommend installing [Rustup](https://rustup.rs/) instead, have you tried it? There might be an RPM package for rustup, otherwise you can install it manually from the given link.

Comment: Do you know the SKU that this system uses?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install rust via yum, I recommend installing from [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

1. If not already installed, install the EPEL repo RPM - eg for RHEL7:

   ```
   yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
   ```

   also enable optional extras in the RHEL repo as they may be required as dependancies:

   ```
   subscription-manager repos --enable "rhel-*-optional-rpms" --enable "rhel-*-extras-rpms"  --enable "rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms"
   ```

   The above instructions are from the EPEL page linked above.
2. Install rust & cargo via yum

   ```
   yum install rust cargo
   ```

EPEL seems to keep the rust packages fairly up to date - they currently stock 1.32 while the latest is 1.33 - but if you want to be on the latest, or use nightly, then rustup is the way to go.